# How can I manipulate the model outside of Angularjs controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a controller that I've registered with my module. What I'd like to do however is access the $scope outside of Angular so that I can change the model around. For instance I would like to do the following:

```
var sentboxCtrl = function ($scope){

    $scope.sent = Sent;
    $scope.deleteIcon = deleteIconSource;
    $scope.flagIcon = flagIconSource;
    $scope.attachmentIcon = attachmentIconSource;

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.sent.length ; i ++)
    {
        $scope.sent[i]['checked'] = false;
    }

    $scope.delete = function(element)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.sent.length; i ++)
        {
            if($scope.sent[i].id == element.id)
            {
                $scope.sent.splice(i,1);
            }
        }

    }

    $scope.deleteChecked = function()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.sent.length; i++)
        {
            if($scope.sent[i].checked)
            {
                $scope.sent.splice(i,1);

                // We must account for sent.length changing
                // after splicing so we need to decrement to
                // account for that.
                i --;
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.getModel = function()
    {
        return $scope;
    }

};
```

Where I use sentboxCtrl.getModel to return the scope, and then I can manipulate protperties of the scope outside the normal context.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an object outside of the context of angular, and then inside of your controller function, assign its value to $scope:

```
var controllerScope = null;
var sentboxCtrl = function ($scope){
    controllerScope = $scope;
    ...
}
```

Now you have access to all of the $scope object's properties.